# csv, IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, csv, indexing, iterator, range

I am reading and doing examples from the book *Python Crash Course*. Now I get stuck in reading data from a csv file. I'm trying to get values of `max_temperatures` and read it, but when I did this in the same way as in my book then an error is shown:

```
IndexError:
high = int(row[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
import csv


filename = "sitka_weather_history_2014.csv"
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    highs = []
    for row in reader:
        high = int(row[1])
        highs.append(high)

    print(highs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the input [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehmatthes/sitka_weather_hx/master/sitka_weather_history_2014.csv) contains empty lines, you have to make sure that the list (`row`) is not empty. If it is empty - just skip it.

Something like:

```
for row in reader:
    if row:
        high = int(row[1])
        highs.append(high)
```

Comment: @Matheo I am glad to help.

Comment: And I know that a solution was very simple. In the file there were  empty lines.. .Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

is `high` the first element in the row? If so, remember that Python starts counting from 0 - so it should be `high = int(row[0])`

Comment: No, high is the second element in the row, first is data. That's why I don't know how to get to the second element in the row.

Comment: Here I upload an image of file "sitka_weather_history_2014" https://ibb.co/x8tsyKz

Comment: First of all, please upload this sample data to the question. Questions should be full enough so answerers don't have to ask for clarifications in comments.

Comment: Second of all, maybe your file isn't parsed correctly? It could be that the whole line is read as one long object (and thus no second element in the row). try printing `row[0]` (which is a useful debugging technique) and see what you get in the first element.